# how to place a bitmap image(pin) in center of the canvas circle(blue circle)?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-bitmap

```
   int x = 1460;
   int y = 800;

   BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   myOptions.inDither = true;
   myOptions.inScaled = false;
   myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
   myOptions.inPurgeable = true;

   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
   R.mipmap.map, myOptions);
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
   Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
   canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);
   Bitmap currentPin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
   R.mipmap.pushpin_blue);
   canvas.drawBitmap(currentPin, x, y, null);
```

I placed both pin and circle in same xy coordinates, But it showing like below shown image

[image: I need to place the image on center of the bluie circle]

Comment: You should consider the size of the bitmap you are using. Probably the size of the Pin bitmap is bigger than the blue circle. They both start at the same position but Pin located at the center of the bigger bitmap and as result bottom of the Pin does not locate at the center of the blue circle.

Comment: Even if both of your bitmap's size are equal. you should locate the Pin at `PinX = x ;` `PinY = y - (CircleHeight/2);`

Comment: @MohamadArmoon i don't get this

Comment: An answer added

Comment: 'float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;float w = (density / 420f) * currentPin.getWidth(); float h = (density / 420f) * currentPin.getHeight();
                        currentPin = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(currentPin, (int) w, (int) h, true);
                        canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat(x), Float.parseFloat(y), Float.parseFloat(rad), mPaint);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(currentPin, Float.parseFloat(x) - w / 2, Float.parseFloat(y) - h / 2, null);' its working now  @MohamadArmoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the problem consider you have:
1: 128 * 128 pixel circle
2: 128 * 128 pixel mipmap
Then if both locate in `x=0` and `y=0` the output will be

:[image]

In order to put the bottom of mipmap in center of the blue circle, you should locate the mipmap in `x=0; y=0;` and circle in `x=0; y=64;` the output will be :

[image]

the reason why your mipmap is not placed over the circle is that mipmap size is bigger than the circle. so if:
1: the circle is 32 * 32 pixels 
2: the mipmap is 128 * 128 pixels 
Then if both locate in `x=0` and `y=0` the output will be:

[image]